# Very slow scrolling on android while using table inside a well(pre-scrollable)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, scroll

Hey guys I've built a web app which shows a table inside a well.The number of entries are about 380.But the problem is that scrolling is really choppy and extremely slow on android devices.Can anyone help ?

Here is the html:

```
<div class="well well-xs pre-scrollable myScores text-center">
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover matchTable text-center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Home</th>
      <th>Score</th>
      <th>Away</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="match in matches.list.data.rounds">

     <tr ng-click="matches.showDetail(matches.list.data.rounds[$parent.$index].matches[$index])"ng-repeat="match in match.matches | filter : matches.item">
      <td><b>{{match.team1.name}}</td>
      <td><b>{{match.score1}} - {{match.score2}}</td>
        <td><b>{{match.team2.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And the css,I've tried adding webkit touch scroll.

```
    .table td{
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important;
 }
 .table{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important;
 }
 .well{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important;
 }
 .pre-scrollable{
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important;
 }
```

Comment: Does the page look like it's being rendered one "tile" at a time?

Comment: I've only attached the table part.Rest of the page has no problems.This is a view in angularjs.